# Unprecedented is to "never done before" as "xyz" is to "never done again after"?

Tags: word-request

Or in other words, is there an adjective meaning something "has never been repeated after the first instance"?

[ODO](http://goo.gl/9Wqf1) defines unprecedented as "never done or known before".

For example, in the following sentence, is there an adjective I can use in place of "never again made" so to change it to "through 'xyz' efforts"?

> The plot of “A Report to an Academy” is that an ape having shed his simian nature transforms into a human through speech and reaches the position he is at now by attaining the refinement of an average European through efforts *never again made* on earth.

Comment: I don't think there's a word for this, mostly because it's not something you can every know for sure. The future is infinite, how do you know nobody will ever again do whatever it is?

Comment: @Martha He is asking for a word meaning "has never been repeated after the first instance." That doesn't mean that it will never be repeated after today. Just that it hasn't been repeated so far.

Comment: @Martha But I agree that there doesn't seem to be a good word for this (at least, I can't think of one)

Comment: But the future is not infinite. Haven't you heard? The universe is going to end on 21 December 2012. Oh, wait ...

Comment: Do keep up, @Jay! (apparently they made a mistake in the math, and it's [now expected to end](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130112123859AAMh3al) 21 December **2013** :)

Comment: The reminds me of a humorous definition I saw some years ago: **Vujà dé**: The feeling that nothing like this has ever happened to anyone ever before, and never will again <compare [*Déjà vu*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/déjà-vu?q=déjà+vu)>.

Comment: The catch to predicting the end of the world just six months away is that you don't have time to write books and go on the talk show circuit and get rich. You want to predict doomsday five or ten years away: That's close enough to be menacing -- if you predict doom 100 years away most people won't care as they'll be dead by then anyway -- but far enough away that you have time to get some fame and fortune out of it.

Answer (score 2):

You could say "unrepeated efforts." I'm not sure that there is a better word than that.

Comment: The only "better" word that comes to mind is **unrepeatable** - depending on whether the thing is *inherently* a "one-off" or just happens to have been unrepeated at the time of describing it thus.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that the question is looking for unrepeated rather than unrepeatable. But that is another possibility.

Comment: Well, OP's actual example is fantasy anyway. I know *A Report to an Academy* is just a story, but in the real world such a thing couldn't happen *once*, let alone maybe again in the future.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed :) I was just saying that because I think "unrepeated" is a better substitute for "never again happened" than "unrepeatable" is.

Answer (score 1):

How about "last" or "final"? "It was the last time any one did that" or "This was the final battle in the war".

Answer (score 0):

*Unduplicated* / *unduplicatable* or *unique* / *one-of-a-kind* could go in there, I think.

Comment: *Unique* and *one-of-a-kind* imply both unprecedented and not repeated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of the following:

- Never duplicated.
- Never yet duplicated.
- Never seen again.
- Never yet seen again.
- Never repeated

*"...through efforts never again witnessed on the Earth."*